# R, Shiny - create Crosstab counting specific value with filters

Tags: r, shiny, crosstab, dt

I have a table in SSMS that I'm querying to try and produce a Crosstab table in R, Shiny. Here is my sample data:

```
HouseNum   SwitchNum   Date         Flipped
1          123         2/26/2019    U
1          123         2/26/2019    D
1          123         2/26/2019    U
1          123         2/26/2019    D
1          123         2/26/2019    U
1          456         2/26/2019    U
1          456         2/26/2019    D
1          456         3/1/2019     U
1          789         3/6/2019     U
1          789         3/6/2019     D
1          123         3/8/2019     U
1          123         3/8/2019     D
1          123         3/8/2019     U
1          123         3/8/2019     D
2          1122        3/8/2019     U
2          1122        3/8/2019     D
2          1122        3/8/2019     U
2          3344        3/9/2019     U
2          3344        3/9/2019     D
2          3344        3/10/2019    U
2          3344        3/10/2019    D
```

We have houses with light switches. We record when they are flipped Up (U) and Down (D). My goal is to produce a Crosstab in R that would group HouseNum and SwitchNum, and count how many times the switch went Up and Down on each Date. It would ultimately show this:

```
HouseNum    SwitchNum   2/26/2019   3/1/2019    3/6/2019    3/8/2019    3/9/2019    3/10/2019
1           123         U(3),D(2)                           U(2),D(2)       
1           456         U(1),D(1)   U(1)                
1           789                                 U(1),D(1)           
2           1122                                            U(2),D(1)       
2           3344                                                        U(1),D(1)   U(1),D(1)
```

Here are the library's I currently use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(RJDBC)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
library(shinyBS)
```

And here are the one's I've tried for creating this Crosstab:

```
library(xtable)
library(reshape)
library(rpivotTable)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
```

I like how the tables look in DT and the sorting and filtering functionality that comes with it. I'd like to use similar functionality with the Crosstab if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a concat field in my SQL query to output U or P with a COUNT(Flipped) then outputting it in R as follows:

```
dcast(df, HouseNum + SwitchNum ~ Date, value.var = "Flipped", fun.aggregate = toString)
```